# centos 6.2 gives read permission denied when root has set read permissions to all users

Tags: centos, permissions, chmod, centos6.2, dropbox

Installing Dropbox on Centos 6.2 owned by root.
Demonstrating that the dropbox folder is owned by root with read permissions to all

"root" user gives read permissions to all users

```
[root@localhost Dropbox]# ls -la
total 436
drwxr--r--. 6 root root   4096 Jul 17 20:01 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   4096 Jul 11 20:11 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root     29 Jul 17 20:01 .dropbox
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 151552 Jul 17 20:03 .dropbox.cache
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   4096 Jul 11 19:28 ePubs to Share
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   4096 Jul 11 20:14 ePubs to Share (1)
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 269894 Jun  7  2010 Getting Started.pdf
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root   4096 Jul 17 20:03 stagbuild
[root@localhost Dropbox]# cd ..
[root@localhost DropboxRoot]# ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Jul 11 20:11 .
drwx------. 48 epub epub 4096 Jul 17 20:01 ..
drwxr--r--.  6 root root 4096 Jul 17 20:01 Dropbox
[root@localhost DropboxRoot]#
```

But the "epub" user cannot see/read any files in this directory:

```
cd DropboxRoot
[epub@localhost DropboxRoot]$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root 4096 Jul 11 20:11 .
drwx------. 48 epub epub 4096 Jul 17 20:01 ..
drwxr--r--.  6 root root 4096 Jul 17 20:01 Dropbox
[epub@localhost DropboxRoot]$ ls -la Dropbox/
ls: cannot access Dropbox/stagbuild: Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/Getting Started.pdf: Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/ePubs to Share (1): Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/.: Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/..: Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/.dropbox.cache: Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/ePubs to Share: Permission denied
ls: cannot access Dropbox/.dropbox: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ..
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .dropbox
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? .dropbox.cache
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ePubs to Share
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? ePubs to Share (1)
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Getting Started.pdf
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? stagbuild
[epub@localhost DropboxRoot]$
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a directory, read permission isn't enough. You also need execute permission in order to enter the directory.